# Found this .htaccess in a folder that had malware i was clearing out

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I got a report that there was malware on a site, so I went in and found a php file (removed) that was doing some base64 stuff and an htaccess file that was uploaded by the original dev as part of a Magento plugin: `Amasty - Product attachments`

it was found in the folder: `/media/dhl/`

Can anyone tell me what this bit of .htaccess scripting does?  I have removed it, but I want to understand it

.htaccess

```
Options All -Indexes
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_flag engine 1
</IfModule>
AddHandler php5-script .php
AddHandler php5-script .gif
Options +ExecCGI
AddType text/html .shtml 
AddHandler server-parsed .shtml
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
AddType application/x-httpd-php .fla
AddType application/x-httpd-php .phtml
AddType application/x-httpd-php .gif
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php4
AddType application/x-httpd-php .zip
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
</IfModule>
```

I am not saying Amasty put it there (I have used many of their plugins without issue and feel they are a reliable company for Magento modules), just that the file was uploaded to the git repository at the same time as that module